# Python: Check if ConfigParser key is not empty

Tags: python, config

How can I check if a ConfigParser key has content in it?
I don't want to check if the key exists, I want to know if it has any value.

Example config.ini

```
[optionalConfigs]
option1 = something
option2 = 38
option3 = ;empty
```

Example Script

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(config.ini)

# None of this gave me output
if config.get('optionalConfigs', 'option1'):
    print("Option 1 has content")
if config.get('optionalConfigs', 'option2'):
    print("Option 2 has content")
if config.get('optionalConfigs', 'option3'):
    print("Option 3 has content")
```

There is a ConfigParser built-in function for that or I need to do other things?

Comment: Retrieve it's value and check it? `if config['key']`

Comment: Using `if config.get(whatever):` and then `print("Config key detected")` I don't get any print output, @OlvinRoght

Comment: If the key is under a section you'll need `config['section']['key']`

Comment: If the key exists, it has "content", that is some object associated with it. That object may be `None`. Can you write a small script demonstrating the problem? 1 config param should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I already had both section and key under my `config.get` call, but thanks for the help, @Ishan

Comment: So how are we supposed to know that you "had both section and key under my config.get" since you haven't posted code? Please post a demo script and config file.

Comment: I just edited the post adding examples, @tdelaney

Comment: @GospelBG, `if config.get('optionalConfigs', {}).get('option1'):`

Comment: Implementing the code you commented gave me `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'` in configparser optionxform. @OlvinRoght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for that. By default, the parser does not allow inline comments. In your example

```
option3 = ;empty
```

`option3` has the value `";empty"`. You can change that with a list of strings that can be used as inline comments

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes=[";"])
```

Now the value of `option3` will be an empty string as if you had configured

```
option3 =
```

Notice that since the option has the equal sign, you are assigning everything to the right, which is an empty string. Had you simply configured

```
option3
```

that would raise an error because no value was assigned. That behavior can be configured also, but that is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the `ConfigParser get` code.
As you can see 2 exceptions can be thrown:

1. NoSectionError  - when section cant be found
2. NoOptionError - when option cant be found

   ```
   def get(self, section, option):
        opt = self.optionxform(option)
        if section not in self._sections:
            if section != DEFAULTSECT:
                raise NoSectionError(section)
            if opt in self._defaults:
                return self._defaults[opt]
            else:
                raise NoOptionError(option, section)
        elif opt in self._sections[section]:
            return self._sections[section][opt]
        elif opt in self._defaults:
            return self._defaults[opt]
        else:
            raise NoOptionError(option, section)
   ```

Comment: I don't get any error, just I don't get any output from the if statement. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @GospelBG, you just need to think a bit. Let's say that `ConfigParser()` is a nested dictionary, so just look how to access to values in nested dictionary. It's basics of python. You spent so much time writing this question, just take a look on basic python tutorial of `configparser` module docs and find a solution there.